# Why am I getting "apt-setup/security_host ubuntu doesn't exist" while instaling from pressed?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, preseed

I am trying to install the 12.04 desktop using preseed file, same file I use for 12.04 server installation. It works fine for the server but on desktop I am getting:

```
apt-setup/security_host ubuntu doesn't exist
```

and installation stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was a bug - Fix released.

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-setup/+bug/728710